# Eloquent all records relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build an alternative relationship that returns all records instead of only related records.  I have tried returning a query builder, but that doesn't work, it must be a relationship. What should I return to make this work?

```
public function devices()
{
    if ($this->admin) {
        // return all devices relationship instead
    } else {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Device', 'permissions');
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://implode.io/XXLGG8

Edit: I'd like to continue building the query in most cases, not just get the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually went a slightly different way and used a scope:

```
protected function scopeHasAccess($query, User $user)
{
    if ($user->admin) {
        return $query;
    }

    return $query->join('permissions', 'permissions.device_id', "devices.id")
        ->where('permissions.user_id', $user->user_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The devices() function in your model is expected to return a relation, you shouldn't add the if statement there. Make your devices() function like this:

```
public function devices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Device', 'permissions');
}
```

In your User model add a new function:

```
public function getDevices() {
    if($this->admin === true) {
        return Device::all(); 
    } 

    return $this->devices();
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$admin->getDevices(); // will return all devices
$user->getDevices(); // will return only relations
```

Comment: This causes Eloquent to fetch devices from SQL, then I would need to run additional SQL queries to get relationships of the devices.  This is not optimal if there are tens of thousands of devices.

Also, your getDevices() function returns either a collection or relationship.

Comment: Relations return a collection, so in both cases you get a collection from getDevices(). No need to run additional queries. Check Fiddle: https://implode.io/Ly1WXH

Comment: Relations return a collection after calling ->get() on them.

Comment: Check the Fiddle, it works. No need to call ->get().

Comment: ->pluck() calls ->get() and also works on collections

Comment: Thanks for the help, lead me to where I wanted to go with a scope.

Answer (score 0):

Add `devices` [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) method to the `User` model and implement your logic there.

```
public function getDevicesAttribute() {
    if ($this->admin) {
        return Device::all();
    }
    return $this->getRelationValue('devices');
}
```

See updated "[fiddle](https://implode.io/04Gy5C)".

Comment: Could be a good solution if you don't need to eager load things.